# Show DIV Overlay when image is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, overlay, slide

I'm trying to work out how to show a hidden DIV as an overlay when an image is clicked.

I've found this example: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7zsLrgyz/)

Which shows a red square and when you click that it shows the `DIV`. Click it again the DIV disappears.

I'd like to do the same but have the click bound to an image and have the overlay slide out left -> right from the image when the image is clicked.

Anyone any ideas how I can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? I replaced the red box div with an img tag while keeping the same ID, so the script can still reference and perform the action on click. So if you click the image, the jquery still shows/hides the overlay?

http://jsfiddle.net/wacrmfqu/1/

I replaced the red box div with:

```
<img id="clickme" src="http://travel.usnews.com/images/destinations/94/yosemite_mirror_lake_getty_michael_h_spiva.jpg">
```

and changed the css for #clickme to:

```
#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    right: -100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I am.. but the image could be anywhere on the page and the div needs to slide out from there. It's not in a fixed position.